# Developing an app which load nearby places through current location and show data location data into listview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, location, runtimeexception

I am developing an app that can locate nearby places and show data on custom list view through current location.But I get error.

```
package com.sherry.hp.googlemap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;

public class Places1 {

public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getPlaces(jsonArray);
}

private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    int placesCount = jsonArray.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> placeMap = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
        try {
            placeMap = getPlace((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
            placesList.add(placeMap);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return placesList;
}

private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson) {
    HashMap<String, String> googlePlaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String placeName = "";
    String vicinity = "";
    String latitude = "";
    String longitude = "";
    String reference = "";
    String pic = "";

    try {
        if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")) {
            placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name");
        }
        if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")) {
            vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity");
        }
        latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
        longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
        reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference");
        googlePlaceMap.put("place_name", placeName);
        googlePlaceMap.put("vicinity", vicinity);
        googlePlaceMap.put("lat", latitude);
        googlePlaceMap.put("lng", longitude);
        googlePlaceMap.put("reference", reference);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return googlePlaceMap;
}
```

}

This is my class where I pass response of current location.

This is where I get my response and save into Arraylist

```
public class PlacesDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

private JSONObject googlePlacesJson;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
ArrayList<Bean>list1;

@Override
protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {
    list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> googlePlacesList = null;
    Places1 places1 = new Places1();

    try {
        googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
        googlePlacesJson = new JSONObject((String) inputObj[1]);
        googlePlacesList = places1.parse(googlePlacesJson);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Places1", e.toString()+"PlacesDisplayTask");
    }
    return googlePlacesList;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {


    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = list.get(i);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(googlePlace.get("lat")));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(googlePlace.get("lng")));
        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");


        Log.e("TAG","vicinity"+vicinity);

        list1.add(new Bean(lat,lng,placeName,vicinity));








        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
```

}

and after setting Custom listview into the class I got the following error

This is my class where I set Adapter

```
public class RestaurantInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
String getUrl;
TextView textView;
ListView listView;

ArrayList<Bean>list;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant_info);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

Adapter adapter = new Adapter(RestaurantInfo.this,list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

and this is my custom listview adapter class

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<Bean>list;

public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bean> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView name;


    if(view ==  null)
    {
        LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = lf.inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
    }

    name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    name.setText(list.get(i).getPlaceName());



    return view;
}
```

}

and I got the following error, this is my logcat

```
  Process: com.sherry.hp.googlemap, PID: 23247
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sherry.hp.googlemap/com.sherry.hp.googlemap.RestaurantInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.sherry.hp.googlemap.Adapter.getCount(Adapter.java:27)
    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:613)
    at com.sherry.hp.googlemap.RestaurantInfo.onCreate(RestaurantInfo.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
```

Comment: Try to check object initialization where you are calling .getSize()

Comment: this is my class you can check it

Comment: you can check adapter class where i put getsize

Comment: i have add google place data on bean class then add into listview but i got the error and i dont know why